# $m \times n$ matrix where $m < n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I'm a long distance student and I need some help to bounce ideas off of other people who understand the work. Fellow students are few and far between. So while this is an assignment question, I just need help to check if my logic and understanding is correct

**Question**

Suppose $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix where $m < n$: Which of the following statements is/are true?

A. The non-homogeneous system $Ax =b$ has at least one solution.

B. The homogeneous system $Ax = 0$ has a unique solution.

**Answer**

A: I don't think A is correct. $Ax=b$ will only have at least one solution IF the linear system is **consistent**. In our study guide it said that if $m < n$ then infinitely many solutions exist. But I think this is a trick question.

B: True, homogenous systems always has the trivial solution which is a unique solution.

Comment: One way to resolve the matter is to do a standard row-reduction to echelon form. But ponder what the equation $Ax=0$ represents geometrically.

Comment: I understand that if I use row-reduction and come across a contradiction, then there is no solution to the system. 

As you can see though, no specific matrix is given.

So I'm not sure if $Ax=b$ will without doubt have a solution if $m<n$.

$Ax=0$ I think means that all the equations will at least meet at 0 on the graph.

I think

Comment: Rather than being a trick question it may simply be a typo in which $b$ should have been $0$. Anyway, you are correct in saying that consistency needs to be known. Re the geometric interpretation, $Ax=0$ represents a "lower-dimensional plane" (subspace) through the origin and the solutions represent points on it, so non-uniqueness cannot hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are false. For example, consider $m = 3$ and $n = 4$.

For part A, consider:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \qquad\text{and}\qquad
b = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 7
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since the third row of $A$ is all zeroes, any linear combinations of its columns will give us a $0$ in the third entry (and not $7$).

For part B, use the same matrix $A$ from part A and observe that (besides the trivial solution), another solution to the homogeneous system is:
$$
x = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 8 \\ 9
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Will $Ax=0$ always have infinite solutions when $ m<n$ ?

Comment: Yes, at least for the usual infinite fields I guess. Finite fields ... got to check.

Comment: Appreciated. I found a paper online that confirms what you guys/girls have been saying.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Hints.

1. A is false in general, as shown by the system
   $$\begin{cases}
    x+y+z=0\\
    x+y+z=1
    \end{cases}$$
2. B is definitely false, because you have more unknowns than equations.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand B then. All homogeneous systems have a solution, regardless of the number of equations and unknowns. So a unique solution will exist (unknowns = 0) but also infinitely many solutions?

Comment: @Richard The phrase “unique solution” is used to mean the system has *only one solution* as opposed to *infinitely many solutions* (or *no solution*).

Comment: I see where I went wrong! Thank you!